# Sacar comillas del array

Tags: javascript, array

Cómo puedo sacar las comillas de lo que me devuelve este array?
use el comando .join('') para sacar las comas pero no como sacar las comillas del principio y del final.
Les dejo el codigo a ver si saben como puedo hacer y si saben alguna manera de mejorarlo también díganme jajaja

`````
const minusculas = ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"];

const numeros = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,];

const simbolos =  ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "&", "/", "(",")", "=", "?", "¿", "¡", ",", ".", "-", "_"];

let p = document.createElement("p");

let password = [];

function generarPassword(){
    for(password.length = 0; password.length < 4; password.length +1){
    let caracter = mayusculas[Math.floor(Math.random() * mayusculas.length)];
    password.push(caracter);
        }
    for(password.length = 4; password.length < 8; password.length +1){
        let caracter = minusculas[Math.floor(Math.random() * minusculas.length)];
        password.push(caracter);
        }
    for(password.length = 8; password.length < 12; password.length +1){
            let caracter = numeros[Math.floor(Math.random() * numeros.length)];
            password.push(caracter);
        }
    for(password.length = 12; password.length < 16; password.length +1){
                let caracter = simbolos[Math.floor(Math.random() * simbolos.length)];
                password.push(caracter);
        }

}
generarPassword();
console.log(password);

document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(password.join(''));````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente no uses `JSON.stringify`

Quedaría así:

```
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = password.join('');
```

Recuerda que el `JSON.stringify` convierte a json un objeto de javascript, para este caso una cadena en json siempre lleva comillas.

Comment: Ahhh es verdad!!! y habra alguna manera de mostrarlo en pantalla y que salga sin comillas?

Comment: Como te digo, solo no uses `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Ali, pensé que si no usaba JSON.stringify no me lo mostraba en pantalla